# Kivy window closing after running on Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

every time I run the code the kivy window appears and closes by itself, how can I solve this?

```
from kivy.app import App

hello_world = App()

hello_world.run()
```

console:

```
C:\Users\Rafael\Anaconda3\envs\k35\python.exe C:/Dev/excript/app-comerciais-kivy/teste/main.py

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Rafael\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-01-06_13.txt

[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1

[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded

[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system

[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 417.22'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>

[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>

[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider

[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The window closes a few seconds after it appears, no error is reported.
Is there any way to solve this? My installation of python with anaconda is ok. There are no errors in library import and if I add buttons or label's no error happens, it just runs and quits automatically